# Can you Copy a Cancelled Translation Job?

Tags: translation-manager

If a translation job is cancelled in the translation management system it will appear in Tridion with status `cancelled` and will eventually get purged based on the Translation Manager Settings. Or you can choose to delete it before then.

In the `cancelled` state, can we:

- Restart the job?
- Copy the job?

I'm trying to confirm the best way to start translation for the same items and am not sure if we can re-use the cancelled items or if a new job is needed from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy/paste of translation jobs is available in Tridion 2013SP1. The copy of the job will always be created in the "Definition" state.

Comment: I'll delete my answer then... Copy/Paste is SO not the terminology I'd look for for something like that, especially given the send & retry options in the other section of the context menu

Comment: I wonder if a *new* job is preferred/needed so it appears differently on the translation management system (TMS or Worldserver) side? Copy/Paste surprised me probably because the Publishing Queue was the closest metaphor I had for understanding the Translation Job list.

Comment: The publishing queue does not capture as much data around the items included as a Translation Job does. And a translation workflow is a lot more complex than what happens when publishing, so you should never expect to be able to "restart" a translation workflow. The bill might already have been send and the translators might already have collected their fee - all based on this workflow.